# What is the difference between DateTime functions?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datetime

What is the difference between `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Is there any performance difference?

**Update :** I read this article ( http://www.nayyeri.net/the-darkness-behind-datetime-now ) and I think we have a substantioal difference, don't you think ? I guess there should be something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing alternatives to DateTime.Now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561791/optimizing-alternatives-to-datetime-now), and related to [Computing Time in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrperfblog/archive/2009/09/08/computing-time-in-net.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to
>   the current date and time on this
>   computer, expressed as the local time.

[DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx)

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to
>   the current date and time on this
>   computer, expressed as the Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC).

As for performance DateTime.Now is a little slower because of time zone adjustments.

You can find more details in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151/datetime-now-vs-datetime-utcnow) thread.

Answer (score 3):

- `DateTime.Now` - your OS system local time.
- `DateTime.UtcNow` - UTC (GMT 0) time. [What is UTC time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Performance-wise - `Now` is slower than `UtcNow`, as `Now` actually calls `UtcNow` and does a few extra adjustments. However, the performance gain is minuscule and you can neglect it, unless you run this for enormous number of times repetitively.

Comment: A fine answer, but remember to mark your changes clearly if you change your answer after the grace period.

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx) - Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

[DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) - local time

You should not be concerned about any performance difference. You use each where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a measurable difference, but DateTime.UtcNow does less work. DateTime.Now starts with the value of DateTime.UtcNow, looks up your time zone offset in the current system settings and then adjusts the result. It also makes adjustments for daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now` gives your PC date time as per your PC's Time zone

`DateTime.UtcNow` gives your date time as per GMT (Converts tour PC time to GMT and returns datetime)